# Remove delay when interrupting UIView animation with another animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I'm interrupting an in-flight animation with another animation. It's working alright, but there's a significant delay before the animation changes.

When I click <kbd>Reset to 1</kbd> after <kbd>Animate to 5</kbd>, the square on top continues expanding for another second before shrinking. For the square on the bottom, I forced the animation to stop with `layer.removeAllAnimations()` and it shrinks instantly... but, it starts from the full 5x scale value instead of the current value.

[image: Image of the problem]

Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let resetButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    let finishButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    
    let squareView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 30, height: 30))
    let referenceSquareView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 30, height: 30))
    let squareView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 30, height: 30))
    let referenceSquareView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 30, height: 30))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        resetButton.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 80, width: 160, height: 20)
        finishButton.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 140, width: 160, height: 20)
        
        view.addSubview(resetButton)
        view.addSubview(finishButton)
        
        view.addSubview(referenceSquareView)
        view.addSubview(squareView)
        view.addSubview(referenceSquareView2)
        view.addSubview(squareView2)
        referenceSquareView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5, y: 5)
        referenceSquareView2.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5, y: 5)
        
        squareView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        referenceSquareView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        squareView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        referenceSquareView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        
        resetButton.setTitle("Reset to 1", for: .normal)
        resetButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        resetButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resetTo1(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        finishButton.setTitle("Animate to 5", for: .normal)
        finishButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        finishButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(animateTo5(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    @objc func resetTo1(_ sender: UIButton!) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
            self.squareView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        }
        
        self.squareView2.layer.removeAllAnimations() /// removing animations for the bottom square
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
            self.squareView2.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        }
    }
    @objc func animateTo5(_ sender: UIButton!) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
            self.squareView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5, y: 5)
        }
        
        self.squareView2.layer.removeAllAnimations() /// removing animations for the bottom square
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
            self.squareView2.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5, y: 5)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can change the animation instantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call self.squareView2.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5, y: 5), squareView2 is immediately has transform value 5 without waiting for 3s(even though you change the duration to 3600s). The animation that the rectangle size increasing you are seeing in the app is just an animation layer. So, if you call removeAllAnimations,it will immediately show the squareView2 with transform value 5.

To work around this issue, I think you can use a timer instead. Set a flag **scale** with value 1. And then, when you tap "Animate to 5", for every 0.3s, increase **scale** for 0.5. So if you want to stop, just invalidate the timer and schedule another timer to decrease the **scale** value

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense. But a timer for animations? That seems kind of overboard

Comment: It sounds doesn't good but I think it can solve your problem. I have tried to use the timer(0.1) for deceleration animation and everything works fine without any performance issues

Comment: I actually just used `UIViewPropertyAnimator` instead, but I guess timer will work.